# How to export results from Query Summary from Kusto Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to compare different where statements in my Kusto query using Kusto Explorer app, so I would like to export the result from the Query Summary tab.

In case has a query or a way to export this manually, it would be awesome.

Is it possible?

[image: Query Suummary]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kusto.Explorer, if you switch to the `QueryCompletionInformation` tab in the result set, you can see & copy the `QueryResourceConsumption` payload

[image: Kusto.Explorer - Query resource consumption]